# Importing data from links to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of links from which I have to manually detect if the product is in stock or not. Is there any import function in google that I can use to identify whether or not the specific product is in stock without opening the link. Can Importxml or importhtml be used?

https://www.katespade.com/products/the-little-better-sam-daisy-dots-small-shoulder-bag/767883202005.html?cgid=ks-new-arrivals-view-all

Comment: does the link contains any argument for item number ?

Comment: this is links from websites like sephora, nordstrom. like wise.

Comment: is there any arguments within the link ? write links example with in the question pls

Comment: I have added the link in the question

Comment: is this 767883202005 item code exist on your stock db?

Comment: No, it doesn't.my work is to go to these links and see if the product is in stock or not. if it is in stock i then have to go to my ecommerce website which doesn't have any link to this particular website and update the status.

Comment: oh , i got you , thats called page scrapping  , yes you can do that

Comment: Oh ok. what do i have to use? because this part differs from website to website

Comment: there is many ways to do scrapping , if you are using chrome , try installing this extention https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper-free-web-scra/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn

Comment: oh ok, thank you so much. I will try this and get back if I face any difficulties. Thank you for your time!

Comment: availability api which returns JSON: https://www.katespade.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Shop-Site/en_US/Product-GetAvailability?pid=767883202005&Quantity=0 . you can try loading the JSON yourself with importdata, a third party extension like importfromweb or with a script like this https://www.geckoboard.com/blog/how-to-import-json-data-to-a-google-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='jss250']")
```

[image]